# check for windows installer mutex availability

Tags: c#, windows-installer

In one of my integration tests, I have two threads that uninstall then install a program but when run in sequence they generate an error `Failed to grab execution mutex. System error 258.`

To get around this I have to sleep after the uninstall. I tried checking if the msiexec process was running but there were consistently 2-3 so it's not a good indicator. Is there a way to check if the msiexec execution mutex is available?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
    bool msiIsRunning = false;
    try
    {
        using(var mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(@"Global\_MSIExecute"))
        {
            msiIsRunning = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       // Mutex not found; MSI isn't running
    }
```

Comment: BTW, remember that technically MSI isn't always a service.  Win 9x platforms don't support windows services.

Comment: An old question, but it would be better to use Mutex.TryOpenExisting instead of Mutex.OpenExisting--exceptions shouldn't be used for program flow, especially in the very common case that MSI isn't running.