# How to detect a running MSI Installation

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I'm looking for a way to detect if a Windows Installer installation is already in progress. What I've found out so far is:

- Checking the Registry key:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress
- Using the Windows Installer API function **MSIInstallProduct** with a dummy file which then would return the specific error code.

Does anybody know a smarter solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as this:

[check for windows installer mutex availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144268/check-for-windows-installer-mutex-availability)

and this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/01/23/516454.aspx

Question 1:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2005/11/09/487559.aspx

Comment: MSDN Blog links are broken. Active link is now https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/waiting-for-msiexec-exe-to-finish/