# Programmatically detect MSI package being installed

Tags: windows-installer

I would like to know if a package is being installed/upgraded.

MSI engine sets a global mutex but doesn't relate to the product.

One idea I have is to scan running msiexec instances and check the command line parameters to determine the msi file and scan for its product code, but I would like to see if there is a better option although couldn't find any suitable API.

Thanks

Comment: Added one more link to actual code that uses the MSI API. I can dig up further samples if need be, but don't want to "overlink" like I normally do.

Comment: What type if sutable API do you want? You can take a snapshot and check the executable name msiexec.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Major Upgrade***: If your MSI is performing a major upgrade, then the product code of the previous version will be added to the property specified as the **ActionProperty** in the [**Upgrade table**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/upgrade-table) of the newest package. In WiX this property is generally called **`WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED`** by convention, but it can be called anything.

In other words, checking whether **`WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED`** or an equivalent property has any value at all can be used to detect that an upgrade is taking place.

***UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE***: In the older setup - the one that is being uninstalled during the major upgrade - the built-in MSI property (as opposed to one you declare) **`UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`** will be set to the product code of the newer setup. *In other words you can use this property (**`UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`**) in conditions in the old package, but it will not be set in the newer setup*. This is a very common confusion. Please see this answer for a better description of this confusion: [Run Wix Custom action only during uninstall and not during Major upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075759/run-wix-custom-action-only-during-uninstall-and-not-during-major-upgrade/51090120#51090120)

***Finding Installed Product***: You can get the product code for an installed product easily: [How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup) [The MSI API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/windows-installer-reference) features a lot of methods and properties that can be used to determine pretty much whatever you want about an installed MSI. It can be accessed via [COM, Win32, Managed code](https://serverfault.com/questions/577969/is-it-possible-to-disable-msiexec-help-gui/596519#596519).

> **UPDATE**: [the script here shows how to identify related products by means of the MSI API RelatedProducts call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49077469/129130). Towards bottom.

---

***Some Links***:

- [Run Wix Custom action only during uninstall and not during Major upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075759/run-wix-custom-action-only-during-uninstall-and-not-during-major-upgrade/51090120#51090120) (more elaborate description of the properties mentioned above - different words and formatting)
- [MSI Tip: Informing the User When a Major Upgrade Will Take
  Place](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/nl_article_DEV_MajorUpgradeUI.pdf) (Flexera)
- [wix installer update process and confirmation dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104204/wix-installer-update-process-and-confirmation-dialog/48106587#48106587) (An implementation in VBScript - of all things - showing a dialog to the user on major upgrade. I would not recommend this, but it is just a sample).
- [check for windows installer mutex availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144268/check-for-windows-installer-mutex-availability)

Comment: Hi Stein, seeing my own question, noticed I forgot to mention I want to detect "OUTSIDE" msiexec/installer process.

Answer (score 0):

Because I want to detect what is Windows Installer installing but out-of-proc, this is what I did so far:

1. Scan all processes and analyze all instances of `C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe` and `C:\Windows\SysWow64\msiexec.exe`
2. Get the command-line parameter and check if `/I` was used.
3. Because the msi file specified in the command line may not contain a full path and the process' current directory may be different than the one when process was started, I used the following method to scan for the package.
4. Using `VirtualQuery` and `GetMappedFileName` scan the process looking for all memory mapped files
5. For each memory mapped file, try to open it using `MsiOpenDatabase`. `MsiOpenPackage` won't work because the package is in use by the installer.
6. Run the SQL to get the `ProductCode` and `UpgradeCode` from the `Property` table.